# Bash script - Run commands that correspond to the lines of a file

Tags: bash, file, command

I have a file like this (text.txt):

```
ls -al
ps -au
export COP=5
clear
```

Each line corresponds at a command. In my script, I need to read each line and launch each command.

**ps: I tried all these options and with all of them I have the same problem with the command "export". In the file there is "export COP=5", but after running the script, if I do echo $COP in the same terminal, no value is displayed**

Comment: If you don't know where this file comes from, you'd better take care to run in a `chroot`'ed environment

Comment: If he does not know where the file comes from he should not execute it at all. Chrooting would only be a basic layer of protection, you can't trust it.

Comment: Regarding the "ps": variables defined in a (normal) script never apply to the parent shell, even when exported (export marks them to be exported to child processes; there's no way to export to a parent process). If you want to define variables in the script and have them still be defined after the script finishes, you need to run the script with `source` rather than as a normal script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while IFS= read line; do eval $line; done < text.txt
```

Be careful about it, it's generally not advised to use eval as it's quite powerful and as easy to be abused.
However, if there is no risk of influence from unprivileged users on text.txt it should be ok.

Comment: To protect escaped chars and whitespace, use `while IFS= read -r line`

Comment: This works great! I have just a problem with the command "export". In the file there is "export COP=5", but after running the script, if I do echo $COP in the same terminal, no value is displayed

Comment: that's because it's in another bash shell, after execution it exits the shell so all variables in there are lost.
I do not know wha tyou exactly try to do but if you want to keep some variables you can for example write the exports into a file (echo 'export COP=5' >> variables.source) and then "source variables.source" after execution to get the variables into your bash shell.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat test.txt | xargs -l1 bash -c '"$@"' echo
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid confusion I would simply rename the file from `text.txt` to `text` and add a shebang (e.g. `#!/bin/bash`) as the first line of the file. Make sure it is executable by calling `chmod +x text`. Afterwards you can execute it as expected.

```
$ cat text
#!/bin/bash
ls -al
ps -au
clear

$ chmod +x text
$ ./text
```